# How tTo Read Re-Sizable div Width In To a Variable - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I am following below css to resize div. Now I need to know how much width user chosen for div.

Is there any possibility to do that?

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 300px;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer does not support the resize property.</p>

<div>Let the user resize both the height and the width of this div element.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your div have an id, then you can try `document.getElementById( ID_OF_DIV ).offsetWidth`

Comment: Can I use ngModel for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $( window ).resize(function() {  // this to get windows width
     console.log( $( window ).width() );
    });

 $('#div-resizable').resize(function() {  // this to get div width
     console.log( $(this).width() );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I guess that you have a re-sizable div and you wish to know the width of the div each time when the user re-sizes the div. Suppose your div have the following id - 'div-resizable', then you can try this,

```
var currentWidth = document.getElementById( 'div-resizable' ).offsetWidth;
```